# Check whether object is a numpy ArrayLike

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

Numpy has a type hint [`ArrayLike`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.ArrayLike) that is supposed to cover pretty much all objects you might want to convert to a numpy array (e.g. lists, objects implementing `__array__` and some more).
It can be used like any type hint:

```py
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike 

def some_func(a : ArrayLike):
    print(a)
```

But it might happen that you want check whether an object is an `ArrayLike` during runtime:

```py
def some_func(a):
    if type(a) == ArrayLike: # Does not work
        print(a)
    if issubclass(a, ArrayLike): # Raises an error
        print(a)
    if isinstance(a, ArrayLike): # Raises an error
        print(a)
```

Is something like this possible using `ArrayLike`? Or should I use another method?

MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike 

class MyArrayLike:
    def __array__(self, dtype = None):
        return np.asarray([0, 1])

def some_func(a : ArrayLike):
    if type(a) == ArrayLike:
        print(a)
#    if issubclass(a, ArrayLike):
#        print(a)
#    if isinstance(a, ArrayLike):
#        print(a)

a = MyArrayLike()
some_func(a)
```

Comment: in your case I would use hasattr and check for `"__array__"`

Comment: Maybe by using a try-except block in which you actually try to convert to a numpy-array?

Comment: "Numpy has a type hint ArrayLike that is supposed to cover all objects that can be converted to a numpy array" - not quite. It's supposed to cover *most* things you'd be *likely to want* to convert to an array. It deliberately excludes a lot of cases, because just about anything is technically an arraylike, but treating most things as arraylike is usually an error. (See the ["Differences from the runtime NumPy API" section](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#differences-from-the-runtime-numpy-api).)

Comment: @DaniMesejo Lists are array-likes as well, so this does not cover all cases.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I clarified my question accordingly

Comment: @ShlomiF this falls under what user2357112 wrote, that pretty much anything can be converted to an array, but ArrayLike covers the cases you probably want to convert

Comment: `__array__` is a method where by a class can specify how it will turned into an array.  It's been added as more third party packages build on and extend `numpy`, and need a way to respond to a `np.array(an_object)` command.  Without it, `np.array` checks if the object is list-like (an iterable).  `np.array` can always make a 0d object dtype array.  What we usually want is a multidimensional numeric (or string) dtype array, not some object fallback alternative.